# Using the getline()

Tags: c++

hi there can someone explain to me why are these two programs different?

```
int main (){
    string line;
    while (getline(cin,line)){
        cout << line;
    }
}
```

---

```
int main (){
    string line;
    while (getline(cin,line)){
        cout << line << endl;
    }
}
```

It seems like the second program prints everything out while the first program will only print the last line for some reason. I'm working on an assignment grabbing lines from a file with IO redirection but when I want to print the lines out I'm forced to print a newline character to get all the lines out.

Comment: One prints `endl`, the other does not.

Answer (score 5):

`getline` discards the newline at the end of the input. However, on Windows, the newline delimiter is actually `\r\n`, i.e. a carriage return followed by a newline. Thus, `getline` ends up storing a string ending with a carriage return.

When you print a line ending with a carriage return, the console will print the text and back the cursor to the beginning of the line (since that's what a carriage return does). Normally, a newline would then push the cursor to the next line, but since the text doesn't contain a newline, the next line gets printed starting from the start of the current line -- overwriting the current line. That's why you only see the last line.

Thus, if you want to print out the lines, you have to output the `endl` that `getline` discards.

Comment: thanks so much I was wondering why I wasn't printing all my lines from the text file...I guess I got to check for a return carriage process the current line then print.